# Using Tweepy in iPython Notebook (Twitter API) - error "data must be a byte string"

Tags: python, api, python-2.7, twitter, tweepy

I am using tweepy in python (version 2.7) to obtain twitter data.  I have been able to obtain historic tweets, but when trying to obtain the same results with code for live stream I get the error "data must be a byte string".

I've imported all of the relevant packages and have previously defined my consumer token, secret & access token, secret etc.

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token, consumer_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)


class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.author.screen_name, status.created_at, status.text

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:',  status_code
        return True 

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True 

streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
streamingAPI.filter(track=['cats'])
```

The error message looks like this:

```css
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-262a8f805ba0> in <module>()
     39 
     40 streamingAPI = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
---> 41 streamingAPI.filter(track=['cats'])

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.pyc in filter(self, follow, track, async, locations, stall_warnings, languages, encoding)
    426         self.session.params = {'delimited': 'length'}
    427         self.host = 'stream.twitter.com'
--> 428         self._start(async)
    429 
    430     def sitestream(self, follow, stall_warnings=False,

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.pyc in _start(self, async)
    344             self._thread.start()
    345         else:
--> 346             self._run()
    347 
    348     def on_closed(self, resp):

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.pyc in _run(self)
    237                                             stream=True,
    238                                             auth=auth,
--> 239                                             verify=self.verify)
    240                 if resp.status_code != 200:
    241                     if self.listener.on_error(resp.status_code) is False:

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    459         }
    460         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 461         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    462 
    463         return resp

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.pyc in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    571 
    572         # Send the request
--> 573         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    574 
    575         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.pyc in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    368                     decode_content=False,
    369                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 370                     timeout=timeout
    371                 )
    372 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.pyc in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, **response_kw)
    516             httplib_response = self._make_request(conn, method, url,
    517                                                   timeout=timeout,
--> 518                                                   body=body, headers=headers)
    519 
    520             # If we're going to release the connection in ``finally:``, then

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.pyc in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, **httplib_request_kw)
    328         # conn.request() calls httplib.*.request, not the method in
    329         # urllib3.request. It also calls makefile (recv) on the socket.
--> 330         conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
    331 
    332         # Reset the timeout for the recv() on the socket

C:\Python27\lib\httplib.pyc in request(self, method, url, body, headers)
    999     def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}):
   1000         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1001         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
   1002 
   1003     def _set_content_length(self, body):

C:\Python27\lib\httplib.pyc in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers)
   1033         for hdr, value in headers.iteritems():
   1034             self.putheader(hdr, value)
-> 1035         self.endheaders(body)
   1036 
   1037     def getresponse(self, buffering=False):

C:\Python27\lib\httplib.pyc in endheaders(self, message_body)
    995         else:
    996             raise CannotSendHeader()
--> 997         self._send_output(message_body)
    998 
    999     def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}):

C:\Python27\lib\httplib.pyc in _send_output(self, message_body)
    852             #message_body was not a string (i.e. it is a file) and
    853             #we must run the risk of Nagle
--> 854             self.send(message_body)
    855 
    856     def putrequest(self, method, url, skip_host=0, skip_accept_encoding=0):

C:\Python27\lib\httplib.pyc in send(self, data)
    824                 datablock = data.read(blocksize)
    825         else:
--> 826             self.sock.sendall(data)
    827 
    828     def _output(self, s):

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.pyc in sendall(self, data)
    218     def sendall(self, data):
    219         while len(data):
--> 220             sent = self._send_until_done(data)
    221             data = data[sent:]
    222 

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.pyc in _send_until_done(self, data)
    208         while True:
    209             try:
--> 210                 return self.connection.send(data)
    211             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantWriteError:
    212                 _, wlist, _ = select.select([], [self.socket], [],

C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.pyc in send(self, buf, flags)
    945             buf = buf.tobytes()
    946         if not isinstance(buf, bytes):
--> 947             raise TypeError("data must be a byte string")
    948 
    949         result = _lib.SSL_write(self._ssl, buf, len(buf))

TypeError: data must be a byte string
```

I'm at a total loss and hope someone can help please.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Install pyOpenSSL 0.15.1

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL

This will fix the error.

Comment: So it does. What?!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too but only after I installed ndg-httpsclient because my Anaconda instillation was giving me an InsecurePlatformWarning.  I did pip uninstall ndg-httpsclient, restarted my iPython Notebook, and then ran the stream again and it worked.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  Sadly, I don't have ndg-httpsclient installed but appreciate you taking the time to try and help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever get this sorted?  I had the same problem when I migrated servers (it did it across management commands from command line and everything.)  The solution seems a bit hackish, but you're left with two options.

You can either monkey patch the OpenSSL usage, which I tried but works only intermittently.

The answer seems to be the new version (3+) uses urllib3, which breaks some backwards compatibility; I had a similar problem using urllib3 in another programme.  I spent about 4 hours trying to get this all to run, on Debian, when the same code has worked on Ubuntu/Centos-6 and Mac OSx - frustrating.

Firstly, try installing requests `pip install requests` - this seems to fix about 60% of the problems I've seen.

If that doesn't work, downgrade tweepy back to 2.3.0 - I've just done this and it's working again.

`pip uninstall tweepy`
`pip install tweepy==2.3.0`

For me, this was a salutory reminder to use pip freeze > requirements.txt when building a new server - I just manually installed everything because it's quite a light install, and have lost half a day as a result.